# Symfony 2: Validating a form for changing password

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm very new to symfony and have trouble with form validation. My aim is validationg a form. I want to secure, that there is a number and a cpital letter in the password, and I also want to define min and max length. I started with validation that the password is not blank, but it doesn't work (error: undefined variable validator). Perhaps anyone has a hint for me?

```
#src/Pso/LogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~ { groups: [changePW] }
```

Controller:

```
public function changePwAction(Request $request)
    {   //Formularerstellung
        $form =  $this->createForm(new UserType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $errors = $validator->validate($user, array('changePW'));

        //Prüfung ob das abgesendete  Formular valide ist
        if (count($errors) > 0) {

        $errorsString = (string) $errors;
        return new Response($errorsString);
        }
        return new Response('The author is valid! Yes!');
    }
```

I don't use the FOSUserBundle. I created a Controller to validate password manually, which works, but to simplify formvalidation my aim is to use different constraints in validation.yml

I would be glad, if anyone has a hint for me.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this. You can just attach all the validation constraints to your properties.

```
Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Regex: 'YOURFAVOURITEREGEX'
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 50
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

You could expand on it and throw certain errors with the "message" parameter. Check the constraint documentation for the exact message name (length is a bit different for example)

Comment: Hell Koalabaerchen, thanks for your answer. I tried this. Therefore I wanted to start with a small constraint. First I only implement the constraint NotBlank in the Entity, but I got the error "ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: validator". What I forgot to mention is, that I use Symfony 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I forgot to define the validator. My Controller works a little bit more with

```
{   //Formularerstellung
    $form =  $this->createForm(new UserType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($user, array('changePW'));

    if (count($errors) > 0) {

    $errorsString = (string) $errors;
    return new Response($errorsString);
    }
    return new Response('The author is valid! Yes!');
}
```

Now I have a new problem. ;-) Thanks for helping.